# Is it safe to prune redbud in summer?

Tags: trees, pruning

I have a young (2-3 year old) redbud tree that has some low branches that are sagging and need to be pruned. I know the preferred time of year to do so has already passed (early summer, just after flowering). Is it still safe to do it now, in mid-summer? Or should I wait until winter? What's the risk/downside if I do it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is safe , you will just lose potential blooms from the buds that have formed on the branches to be removed. That could be a good thing as the tree will not put energy into those missing blooms and could use it to grow . I have done this on various young perennials to encourage more growth.